# How to merge countries to make geomap using d3.js?

Tags: angular, d3.js, topojson, geomap

I am following this example( http://bl.ocks.org/wiesson/ef18dba71256d526eb42 ) to merge the countries based on specific requirement. In this example we have Countries.json that is not available. 
My requirement is to create a geographical map merging the countries using Angular 6. I am merging this code in my another example where i have a geomap using d3.js and angular 6 following geojson and topojson and i'm following this file ( http://raw.githubusercontent.com/andybarefoot/andybarefoot-www/master/maps/mapdata/custom50.json ) to generate world map.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/wiesson/raw/ef18dba71256d526eb42/b98a7e688e0f99ce81e1ffba81f23130186d937b/countries.json

Comment: Thanks for sharing the file. Issue is resolved.